# Gatsby.js: Is there a way to render a component only when the page loaded, but not on the static page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm looking for a way whilst using Gatsby.js React components to prevent certain parts to render on the generated static pages and only render when the page loads in the browser:

```
<ThisComponentRenderedInStaticPages>
  Content renered in static pages.
  <SomeMagicTagPreventsChildrenToRenderOnStaticPages>
    <ThisItemOnlyRendersOnPageLoad />
  </SomeMagicTagPreventsChildrenToRenderOnStaticPages>
</ThisComponentRenderedInStaticPages>
```

Should I compile a separate package for these and include them in a react-helmet element?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the component you don't want generated statically in a ternary checking if `window` is `undefined`.

```
typeof window === 'undefined' ? (
  <div>I'm only generated in the browser.</div>
) : null}
```